# how to return a modified array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, asynchronous, splice

i have a simple function that takes in an array of objects and one object that has been modified. The Goal is to exchange the modified object in the old array of objects and then log the updated array of objects

my Take:

```
 async mutateTodos(currentTodos: ITodos[], editedTodo: ITodos) {
    const Index = currentTodos.findIndex((el) => el.id === editedTodo.id);
    const updatedTodos = currentTodos.splice(Index, 1, editedTodo);
    console.log(updatedTodos);
  }
```

For some Reason, updatedTodos only returns an array containing the old object that was at the index that has been identified properly.
I cant wrap my head around why this doesnt work

Comment: That's how `splice` works. It returns the extracted portion. It mutates the array on which it is called.

Comment: The docs explain this pretty well I think: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

`splice` mutates the array on which the method is called. The return value is not that mutated array, but the slice of the array that was removed from it. In this case it is an array with the old todo.

There are many ways to get the result you want. For instance, you could first create a copy, then call `splice` on it, and then return that mutated copy.

```
    const updatedTodos = [...currentTodos];
    updatedTodos.splice(Index, 1, editedTodo);
    console.log(updatedTodos);
```